# Alerting return value shows correct string whereas storing as variable returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, parent-child, return-value

This returns the expected value:

```
alert($('#previous a').attr("href"));
```

This returns `undefined`:

```
var a = $('#previous a').attr("href");
alert(a)
```

I could not figure out why. Can someone help me :)

Comment: please put your code in codeblocks by adding four spaces in front of each line

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.Try below.

```js
var a = $('#previous a').attr("href");
alert(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="previous">
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `code`
<button id="previous" type="submit" class="btn">
     <a href="/prev/item.html" title="">Previous</a>
</button>
`code`

It's basically the same as you wrote, but however I can't store the href in my variable